# No puedo instalar nuevas dependencias composer en cpanel

Tags: laravel, composer, cpanel

Hola estimados espero su pronta ayuda, no puedo instalar una dependencia en la terminal cpanel para un proyecto hecho en laravel

Cuando coloco el siguiente comando "composer --version" me aparece el siguiente texto, y no se porque una ayuda[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo subiendo proyectos de laravel al servidor y solo copie todos los archivos al hosting que me falta hacer?

Comment: se supone que el laravel es para desarrollar y cuando todo esta ok se sube al servidor, no es logico instalar nada en el server una ves subido el proyecto.

Comment: En mi caso implemente la descarga de reportes en excel asi que instale una libreria en mi laravel local, pero ahora que deseo actualizar mi laravel en el servidor no puedo borrar todos los archivos y subir el nuevo, perderia archivos como imagenes almacenadas

Comment: solamente sube y reemplasa todo el proyecto eso ayudara, y para la proxima usa git

Comment: Temo, una vez hice lo mismo y me salia errores. un compañero borro la carpeta log? pero no recuerdo